# How to get Count of Changes and New Entries to the Table Weekly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement to find out how many new opportunities, and stage change opportunities appear this week compare to the last week. So my plan is to update one table weekly and create a copy and update that table daily.
Is kind of that going to work?

Here is my last week's data (lastWeek)

```
start_date      month       opportunity     Stage   Isit    Expected    Revenue
1/1/2023        January     ABC             Pr      No      200         0
12/31/2022      December    ABC             Pr      Yes     200         200
1/1/2023        January     ABCD            Co      No      50          0
1/1/2023        January     ABCD            Co      Yes     100         100
12/31/2022      December    ABS             Pr      No      550         0
12/31/2022      December    ABS             Co      No      510         0
1/1/2023        January     ABS             Co      No      1060        0
12/31/2022      December    CVD             Pr      No      230         0
1/1/2023        January     CVD             CL      No      120         0
12/31/2022      December    CVD             CL      No      200         0
1/1/2023        January     FES             Co      No      450         0
1/1/2023        January     FES             Pr      No      350         0
12/31/2022      December    FES             Co      No      700         0
12/31/2022      December    FES             Co      Yes     300         300
1/1/2023        January     FES             CL      No      1200        0
12/31/2022      December    JBS             Pr      No      600         0
12/31/2022      December    JBS             Pr      No      400         0
10/30/2022      November    CBD             Co      No      220         0
11/27/2022      December    CBD             Pr      No      220         0
1/1/2023        January     CBD             Pr      No      220         0
10/30/2022      November    CBD             CO      No      220         0
```

This week's data so far (ThisWeek)

```
start_date      month       opportunity     Stage   Isit    Expected    Revenue
1/1/2023        January     ABC             Pr      No      200         0
12/31/2022      December    ABC             Pr      Yes     200         200
1/1/2023        January     ABCD            Co      No      50          0
1/1/2023        January     ABCD            Co      Yes     100         100
12/31/2022      December    ABS             Co      Yes     550         550
12/31/2022      December    ABS             Co      No      510         0
1/1/2023        January     ABS             Pr      No      1060        0
12/31/2022      December    CVD             Pr      No      230         0
1/1/2023        January     CVD             CL      No      120         0
12/31/2022      December    CVD             CL      No      200         0
1/1/2023        January     FES             Co      No      450         0
1/1/2023        January     FES             Pr      No      350         0
12/31/2022      December    FES             Co      No      700         0
12/31/2022      December    FES             Co      Yes     300         300
1/1/2023        January     FES             CL      No      1200        0
12/31/2022      December    JBS             Pr      No      600         0
12/31/2022      December    JBS             Pr      No      400         0
1/1/2023        January     JBS             Co      Yes     600         600
10/30/2022      November    CBD             Co      No      220         0
11/27/2022      December    CBD             Pr      No      220         0
1/1/2023        January     CBD             Pr      No      220         0
10/30/2022      November    CBD             CO      Yes     220         220
1/1/2023        January     CSK             Co      No      300         0
12/31/2022      December    CSK             Pr      No      450         0
1/1/2023        January     CSK             Pr      Yes     500         500
1/1/2023        January     CSK             Co      No      450         0
1/5/2023        January     TGS             Co      Yes     800         800
1/6/2023        January     TGS             Co      No      600         0
```

```
-- I'm trying to do something like this 
Select * from 
ThisWeek t 
left join
lastWeek l 
on t.opportunity <> l.opportunity
and t.Stage <> l.Stage and t.start_date <> l.start_date
```

So basically I want to filter out below

```
start_date      month       opportunity     Stage   Isit    Expected    Revenue     NewOpportunity StageChange
12/31/2022      December    ABS             Co      Yes     550         0           No              Yes
1/1/2023        January     ABS             Pr      No      1060        0           No              Yes
1/1/2023        January     JBS             Co      Yes     600         600         No              Yes
10/30/2022      November    CBD             CO      Yes     220         0           Yes             No
1/1/2023        January     CSK             Co      No      300         0           Yes             No
12/31/2022      December    CSK             Pr      No      450         0           Yes             No
1/1/2023        January     CSK             Pr      Yes     500         500         Yes             No
1/1/2023        January     CSK             Co      No      450         0           Yes             No
1/5/2023        January     TGS             Co      Yes     800         800         Yes             No
1/6/2023        January     TGS             Co      No      600         0           Yes             No
```

and get the
Count   Opportunites

1. no of new distinct opportunites      2         CSK,TGS
2. no of new opportunites               7         CSK,TGS
3. no of Stage Changes                  2         ABS

Any help would be appriciate thanks in advance!

Comment: `LastWeek` and `ThisWeek` are two different table? How do you populate them and what will happen to the tables the week after that? `start_date` format is `m/d/y`?

Comment: That's a strange `left join` btw, it's almost like you're actually looking for a `cross join` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to add a field like "changed timestamp" and create trigger on update and insert which change that field.

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-update-trigger/